I can't get the file generated in slack but I do get the file if it is generated with slack connect
The files arrive with the following format:
const file = {
     "filetype": "jpg",
     "created": 0.
     "id": "random_id",
     "file_access": "check_file_info",
     "user": "",
     "timestamp": 0
}

But only the file generated in slack connect is successfully recovered.
request code:
const { WebClient } = require("@slack/web-api");
const web = new WebClient(token.accessToken);

  const fileUpload = await web.apiCall('files.info',{
            file:file.id
        })
        if(fileUpload.ok){
             console.log(fileUpload.file)
        }

Error: An API error occurred: file_not_found
I emphasize that this works now if the file is generated using slack connect
Expected:
{
    "ok": true,
    "file": {
        "id": "F0S43PZDF",
        "created": 1531763342,
        "timestamp": 1531763342,
        "name": "myfile.jpg",
        "title": "myfile.jpg",
        "mimetype": "image/jpg",
        "filetype": "jpg",
        ...etc
}

Result:
{
code: 'slack_webapi_platform_error',
 data: {
 ok: false,
 error: 'file_not_found',
 response_metadata: { scopes: [Array], acceptedScopes: [Array] }
}

